# Rotate a SurfaceView in xml layout

Tags: android, xml, rotation, surfaceview

How can I rotate a custom SurfaceView in a layout file by 180 degrees?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
      <package.CustomSurfaceView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:rotation="180"
      />
</LinearLayout>
```

Needless to say the above code doesn't work.

Comment: Did you find a way to rotate the surfaceview? I stucked at this and i dont know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't do it by XML (just like you noticed),

the best option is to do it on the canvas before drawing, like this:

```
canvas.rotate(180f);
```

Comment: But what about the touch input then?

Comment: then you have to calculate it during onTouchEvent to flip X and Y to the other side.

Comment: Yep I did it, ok thanks :) Also I think what you wrote is partially wrong because you have to save canvas, rotate, draw and then restore.

Comment: I tried `override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) { canvas?.scale(-1f, 1f)
        super.onDraw(canvas)
}` but it didn't change anything